# What is the difference between the iphone bluetooth devices list showing an encircled (i) and not showing it?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to know what is the difference between the bluetooth connection states, when an iphone is showing a blue i next to a device in it's bluetooth connected device list, vs when it's not showing it. For example, what is the difference between this

[image]

and this

[image]

**More context:**

I am trying to communicate between iphone and CSR8675 bluetooth chip using BLE. CSR provides a BLE communication library called GAIA (which internally uses ios's standard Corebluetooth library, but as far as I understand I do not need to know about what it does internally, and should be able to communicate with the CSR chip using only the functions provided by the GAIA library). To be able to actually send data between the iphone and chip, I need to specifically enable BLE bonding mode in the chip, then select the chip in CSR's sample iphone app's available devices list, then press OK on a confirmation box on the app, after which pairing between iphone and CSR chip is established. This results in a blue i after the device name in the iphone's bluetooth settings windows (2nd picture above). After this I can send BLE data between iphone and chip using the GAIA library functions.

But it's also possible to select the CSR chip on the iphone app's available devices list *without* enabling BLE bonding mode on the chip, which results in the situation shown in the 1st picture above. In this condition it is not possible to send BLE data between iphone and chip.

I am trying to understand more details about how the GAIA library works. So I would like to know (ignoring the CSR ship for now), from the iphone's point of view, what is the difference between a bluetooth device with the blue 'i' (let's call it state A) and a bluetooth device without one (let's call it state B)? Is there a way to programmatically know whether a remote bluetooth device is in state A or B?

Comment: The i means that iOS is paired/bonded with the device; it has exchanged stored encryption keys to enable encrypted communication. There is no way to query this state programmatically. Attempt to read or write a characteristic on the device where encryption is required will trigger the iOS pairing process and dialog.

Comment: @Paulw11 The app calls a CSR GAIA function when a button is pressed in the UI, which sends a GAIA command (an array of around 8 bytes) to the CSR chip, but it doesn't seem to how any indication when this sending failed, due to the device not being paired. What is the correct way to prevent this GAIA command being sent if there is no secure pairing established?

Comment: @Paulw11 My problem is that for pairing to be established the CSR chip must first be put into "BLE bonding mode" before anything else (which involves pressing a hardware button on the chip's module). The app shows the CSR chip as an available bluetooth device even when it's not in BLE bonding mode, and it's possible for the app user to select it (which results in the firs picture). There doesn't seem to be any way for the app to know if the CSR chip is in BLE bonding mode or not.

Comment: Typically an attempt to read or write an "encryption required" characteristic will fail (with an appropriate call to a delegate method) if pairing has not been established.